# How to directly modify array elements through function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this function that uses backtracking to try and solve a sudoku, but it doesn't modify the array directly, but when I log the specific index, it is changed. So it never gets past the first index.

```
function solveBoard(board) {
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] == 0) {
                for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                    board[row][col] = i;
                    console.log(board[row][col]); //logs num
                    console.log(board); //number at [row][col] is still 0
                    if (checkValid(board, row, col)) {
                        if (solveBoard(board)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                board[row][col] = 0;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling the function

```
solveBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let boardArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        let row = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            let square = document.getElementById(`${i}-${j}`);
            if (square.value == "") {
                row.push(0);
            } else {
                row.push(parseInt(square.value));
            }
        }
        boardArray.push(row);
    }
    solveBoard(boardArray);
});
```

Comment: Added how im calling the function to the post

Comment: What's the definition of `checkValid`? In particular, does it only check whether a single cell conflicts with relevant neighbors?

Comment: I ended up fixing it due to the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these two lines. You are putting num in the for loop & then overriding the same position with zero in the below line. Also you don't need to return false until the board is fully solved.

```
board[row][col] = 0;
return false;
```

The fact is your array is being modifying in place but you are changing it later in the same loop. console.log prints updated value(since arrays in JavaScript are by reference, not by value), with your current code, print with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board))).

```
console.log(board[row][col]);//logs num 


console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board))); //number at [row][col] should print num
```

Comment: Those two lines are for backtracking & failure; removing them will cause other (algorithmic) issues.

Answer (score 0):

`solveBoard` has no check for a base case. Consequently, the only way it can be exited is when the inmost loop finishes, which will backtrack and fail, returning the "empty" cell values back to 0. Thus, the board is returned to its initial state as a result of backtracking.

Handle the base case, and the rest should work. However, brute-force Sudoku solutions are liable to take time.